# Arrow heads on coordinate axes

Tags: mathematics

1. Where did arrow heads on coordinate axes appear for the first time?

I checked Descartes' "Discourse on Method, Optics, Geometry, and Meteorology"
but he does not use any arrow heads.

2. In scientific literature the convention seems to be that the arrow head indicates
   the positive direction. However, in the US school system it seems they use
   two arrow heads. Where did that convention appear?